# Freemarker format integer as minutes and seconds

Tags: java, freemarker

I have an integer value that represents a time span in seconds and I shall format it as minutes and seconds: 
Example: I have an integer `durationInSeconds = 341` and want it to be displayed as `05:41`.

The only way I could find for formatting is formatting a date, but i don't have a date -  I have an integer

**This works:**

```
${.now?date?string("mm:ss")}
```

It will output the current minutes and seconds, e.g. `46:50`

**This doesn't work:**

```
${durationSeconds?date?string("mm:ss")}
```

It gives me a error:

> Unparseable date: "341"

Is there an easy way to convert/format the integer value this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numbers can be converted to date/time/datetime via `?number_to_date`/`?number_to_time`/`?number_to_datetime`, but they are not what you want, as they interpret the input as milliseconds passed since the epoch, plus the formatting will count in your time zone. But you have a duration here, not an instant. Thus, you can simply do this:

```
${(durationSeconds / 60)?int}:${durationSeconds % 60}
```

Of course if you need this on multiple places, then you can define a `#macro` for this (then it will be like `<@duration durationSeconds />`), or define a custom number format for this (then it will be like `${durationSeconds?string.@duration}`).

Comment: `${durationSeconds*1000)?number_to_datetime?string("mm:ss")}` does the trick. Thanks

Comment: @Alexander The problem with the `?number_to_datetime` solution is that it only gives the desired output as far as your `time_zone` FreeMarker configuration setting is UTC or other GMT+00 time zone. That setting defaults to the default time zone of the system.

Comment: ok, but in my case this should be ok, because i definitely only want to display **minutes and seconds** and as far as I understand TimeZones, minutes and seconds don't differ between the timezones that are relevant for us (Europe or UTC). Only if the offset to UTC would be `n +  1/2` hours or so, this would matter. But thanks for pointing this out for me.

Comment: Yes, that's true in Europe, as far as I know. (There are zones that compared to UTC end with 30 or 45 minutes elsewhere.)